# How to redirect all the subdomain to http instead of https

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

The htaccess file am using contains

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# First rewrite to HTTPS:
# Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
# the subsequent rule will catch it.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This code helps in redirecting URL from
example.com to https://www.example.com

Problem is, it also redirect subdomains to https://www.sub.example.com

i want subdomains only redirect to http://www.subdomain.example.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `RewriteCond` in `http->https` rule to restrict it to main domain only:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# First rewrite to HTTPS:
# Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
# the subsequent rule will catch it.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: No, its still not working. Cleaned all the browser data and cache. Tried new browser.

Comment: I had already corrected it before applying, But don't know why its not working.

Comment: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?knocktotechs\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# First rewrite to HTTPS:
# Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
# the subsequent rule will catch it.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`  the subdomain m using is crm.knocktotechs.com

Comment: I've checked it but there is no htaccess file in crm.

Comment: can we add another htaccess file in crm folder for this purpose

Comment: Another way to test, rename this .htaccess and then visit `crm` subdomain.

Comment: @anubhava I tried your code and it working. But when I add Google Analytics to sub.domain.com. It counts for domain.com, I can't detect from domain or sub.domain. And have another problem, normal each user visit my site range 2 - 3 minutes. Then add this code to .htaccess, time visit about 40 seconds. Can you check my question? Thanks.

Comment: @anubhava I created at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50803894/google-analytics-dont-detect-subdomain-after-redirect-all-subdomain-to-http

Comment: @anubhava Seem my website is attacked after adding this code to .htaccess. The hacker add the shell to my website thought by local attack

Comment: As I noted from your other question that you are using `nginx` and this solution is `Apache` specific. I suggest you create a new question with all the relevant details and and some experts will be able to help you out.