# Google Analytics don't detect subdomain after redirect all subdomain to http

Tags: php, .htaccess

My website using SSL: https://sharengay.com . I need to add a subdomain like http://hdonline.sharengay.com

I added this code into `.htacess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# First rewrite to HTTPS:
# Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
# the subsequent rule will catch it.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Yes, it works perfectly. URL: http://hdonline.sharengay.com is available.
Have two the problem when adding this code.

The first problem:
When any user visit URL: http://hdonline.sharengay.com . Google Analytics can't detect from the domain (https://sharengay) or subdomain(http://hdonline.sharengay.com). It found it like one URL: `\` - like domain.

Here is image easy to know:

[image]

At I mark in the picture, I tried to visit http://hdonline.sharengay.com but Google Analytics detect is `/`.

The second problem: - I think the problem is not related with code added on `.htaccess`

Normally, each user visits my site range 2 - 3 minutes. From add this code to .htaccess, time visit about 40 seconds. I don't know to add this code to `.htaccess` is affect to time view on my website.
I think: "it's not". But the result is opposite. The subdomain is got video from a service in my country, I think the user can stay here for more than 2 minutes. Instead of only 40s - 1m40s.

Comment: Looks like your sever is `nginx` not `Apache`. All of these rules are not being applied. e.g. `https://sharengay.com/` is not getting redirected to `https://www.sharengay.com/`

Comment: @anubhava Yes, my server is `nginx`